# 404 when redirecting with .htaccess because it's deleting sub-directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I want to do is a URL friendly site by deleting the .html. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+rscares/(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /rscares/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

This is the thing, I'm testing in a **sub-folder** so if I type `example.com/folder/page` works fine but if I do `example.com/folder/page.html` it redirects to `example/page` and I get a **404** because the page doesn't exist. I want to redirect to the same label it was before the redirection. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rscares/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(rscares/.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Did you use `RewriteBase /folder/` after `RewriteEngine On` line? Can you show your `/folder/.htaccess`?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rscares/

Comment: oh not in comments, it is unreadable. Edit your question and post this complete `.htaccess`.

Comment: @anybhave. Hi anubhava, I updated the cod, this is all my .htaccess

Comment: You have my suggested 301 rule before `RewriteEngine On`. See my answer how it is supposed to be.